Did Aquinas say that God cannot destroy a soul?
It seems that that is what he is saying here:

"Now it was shown above (AA. 2, 3) that the souls of brutes are not self-subsistent, whereas the human soul is; so that the souls of brutes are corrupted, when their bodies are corrupted; while the human soul could not be corrupted unless it were corrupted per se. This, indeed, is impossible, not only as regards the human soul, but also as regards anything subsistent that is a form alone. For it is clear that what belongs to a thing by virtue of itself is inseparable from it; but existence belongs to a form, which is an act, by virtue of itself. Wherefore matter acquires actual existence as it acquires the form; while it is corrupted so far as the form is separated from it. But it is impossible for a form to be separated from itself; and therefore it is impossible for a subsistent form to cease to exist" (ST I.75.6).

But I am puzzled because Copleston said:

"from which it follows that it is incorruptible or naturally immortal.  Physically speaking, it could, of course, be annihilated by the God who created it; but its immortality follows from its nature and is not simply gratuitous" (A History of Philosophy Vol. II, Image 1993, 384.)


Not quite, see Farmer, Aquinas on the Immortality of the Human Soul:"While... the soul is in virtue of itself the cause of life, this is insufficient to ensure the immortality of the soul from the principle 'nothing can be separated from itself'. As it stands, the argument allows us to conclude only that the soul cannot cease to be the cause of life, not that soul cannot cease to be actually living... The souls of plants and non-human animals are also the cause of their life, but the immortality of those types of souls is denied by Aquinas."

@wmasse Please give a precise reference to Copleston. - Aquinas answer in ST I.75.6 starts "Respondeo dicendum quod necessarium est dicere animam humanam [...] esse incorruptibilem."

@JoWehler added

@wmasse Now I read the passage from Copleston. But I must confess: Neither do I understand what Copleston means by "Physically speaking", nor do I see that Copleston provides any argument in this passage. - Nevertheless Thomas Aquinas ST I.75.6 clearly says that the soul is incorruptible.
